# iOS Unity3D app unable to access internet / GoogleAdMobSDK

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I've recently developed a mobile Unity3D app, integrated with GoogleAdMobSDK. So far everything works fine on Android, but when I run the app on an iPhone 6 / iOS device I get "GoogleMobileAdsPlugin: Rewarded ad is not ready to be shown."

It also appears that internet generally may be disabled from the app (Safari works fine however).

I noted:

```
[NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x2837c4960, domain=1, instance=1>
```

Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A8 GPU
2020-08-04 20:55:12.747563+1000 HauntedMaze[2115:665921] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x2837c4da0, domain=1, instance=1>

in the logs as well if that helps.

Versions: XCode 11.6 (11E708) - Unity3D 2019.4.6f1 - GoogleAdMobSDK Cocoapods most recent via Cocoapods (7.63.0), iPhone 6 version 12.4.8

Can you think of any additional steps to debug this or a workaround? Am really scratching my head.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your Xcode version?

Comment: XCode 11.6 (11E708) - Unity3D 2019.4.6f1 - GoogleAdMobSDK Cocoapods most recent

Answer (score 1):

For those experiencing something similar, updating to https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v5.3.0

in Unity appears to have fixed the issue.